# Can this Jquery script be simplified?

Tags: jquery

I have the following Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // When the submit button of the new team form is clicked...
    $('#new_team').submit(function () {
        // Disable & rename the save button
        $('input#save_button', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('Saving...');
        // Fade in the saving message
        $("#saving-msg").fadeIn(200);
    });

    // Perform the AJAX request to the server
    $('#new_team').ajaxForm({
        url: "/teams/create.json",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSubmit: function (formData, jqForm, options) { },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success == true) {
                // If no errors then redirect
                window.location = "/teams/" + response.team_id;
            } else {
                // Enable and rename the save button
                $('input#save_button').removeAttr('disabled').val('Save');
                // Output errors
                $("#error_messages").html(errorMessages(response)).hide().fadeIn(300);
                // Fade out save message
                $("#saving-msg").fadeOut(200);
                // Scroll to the top
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is there anyway to simplify this script and also make it reusable for different forms?

- There is only ever one form on a page
- The buttons are always labelled the same
- Each form has a unique ID

Thanks!

Comment: This is not really good practice, but since there is only ever one form, you could just use the selector $('form') to reference the form.  Then to reference the button as a child of said form such that you can use $(this).find('input#save_button').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple of thougths.  Instead of using the ID, you can create a class for the form and have the id of the save button and msg look like this:

```
<id_of_form>_save_button
<id_of_form>_error_msgs
<id_of_form>_saving_msg


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ajax_form').submit(function() {
        $('.save_button', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('Saving...');
        $(this.attr('id')+"_saving_msg").fadeIn(200);
    }
);
```

You can use the same idea for the AJAX request.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use $(this).find, to look for the buttons within the context of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You reference the form's id twice; you could instead abstract the function you pass to `$(document).ready` away into a function which takes an argument (the id of the form) and then just pass in a different name each time using a closure.

```
function abstracted_ajax_form($formid)
{
    ...
}

$(document).ready(function() { abstracted_ajax_form('#new_team'); });
```